# How to perform mathematical functions like addition or subtraction on values received from OData?

Tags: sapui5

my odata is returning me this values from CDS view:

**investmentDone = 18 AND
totalRevenue = 10**

I want to calculate profit from these values and store it in variable ***(profit = investmentDone - totalRevenue)***, so that I can use it in my view to display that value. Any help how can I perform this calculations in controller?

Tx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal approach to do this if you are calculating profit on the UI layer is to use a custom formatter as it is the recommended approach.
https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/0f8626ed7b7542ffaa44601828db20de.html

You can do this adding the below code.

**For the XML View**

```
<Label text="{
parts:[{path:'investmentDone'},
       {path:'totalRevenue'}
    ],
formatter: '.formatter.calcProfit' 
}">
</Label>
```

**Controller JS**

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "sap/ui/demo/wt/model/formatter"
], function (Controller, JSONModel, formatter) {
    "use strict";
    return Controller.extend("sap.ui.demo.wt.controller.InvoiceList", {
        formatter: formatter,
        onInit : function () {

            ...

        }
    });
});
```

**For the Formatter code**, create a new file model/formatter.js

```
sap.ui.define([], function () {
    "use strict";
    return {
        calcProfit: function (iInvestmentDone, iTotalRevenue) {
                return (iInvestmentDone - iTotalRevenue);

        }
    };
});
```

Comment: thanks man, it worked. Just one question if you can help me more, can you also tell me how can I use this value of (iInvestmentDone - iTotalRevenue), to set progress color in PROGRESS INDICATOR control?

Comment: You're welcome. For Progress indicator do this `<ProgressIndicator
    percentValue="{ parts:[{path:'investmentDone'},{path:'totalRevenue'}],formatter: '.formatter.calcProfit' }"
    displayValue="{ parts:[{path:'investmentDone'},{path:'totalRevenue'}],formatter: '.formatter.calcProfit' }%"
    showValue="true"
    state="None" />` Also in you index.html, add this to the bootstrap declaration for enabling complex bindings or the % sign will not be visible : data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest better to do calculation in back end. 
No problem if you have to do it front end. 
Check below code :

```
var fnSuccess = function(oData,oResponse){
var TabData = {
    Data : []
};
var DataArr;

for(i=0;i<oData.results.length;i++){
  DataArr = {
    profit : oData.results[i].investmentDone - oData.results[i].totalRevenue,
    investmentDone : oData.results[i].investmentDone,
    totalRevenue   : oData.results[i].totalRevenue
 }
 TabData.Data.push(DataArr);
}
```

After this code just bind this data to JSON model and set model to table.

Comment: I am using odata model